# Bootstrap Off-canvas Sidebar Left and Right Fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am very interested in this example: http://www.bootply.com/qq78PQIf44 but I need to fix the two sidebar and when the browser size is compatible with iPad (portrait/landscape) i would like to hide the Left Sidebar.

Comment: Questions seeking code help (such as "why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Add a hider class to your sidebar.

```
<div id="sidebar" class="hidden-xs">
...sidebar...
</div>
```

[Full list of helper classes here.](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 0):

Use `hidden-md` and `hidden-sm` to match `display: none` property with the iPad's width

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 sidebar-offcanvas hidden-md hidden-sm" id="sidebarLeft" role="navigation">
```